# How to resize an array in math environment

Tags: graphics, arrays, brackets, mathcal

This is my code:

```
$$
\mathcal{P}_{\left\{ \resizebox{0.02\textwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle 
\begin{array}{l}
\mathcal{B} \\
\mathcal{F}
\end{array}$} \right\}} 
\Psi\left(\vec{r}_{1}, \vec{r}_{2}, \ldots, \vec{r}_{N}\right):=\frac{1}{N !} \sum_{P} \xi^{P} \Psi\left(\vec{r}_{P 1} \vec{r}_{P 2} \ldots \vec{r}_{P N}\right)
$$
```

[image]

however, notice how the curly brackets in the subscript are way too big and font way to small. My goal is to obtain something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Why are you using resize box in math in the first place? Most users should forget about ever having heard `\resizebox`. I'd use use `Bsmallmatrix` from `mathtools`.

Comment: never use resizebox on tables or other text it produces inconsistent font sizes, as you show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single occurrence you can (ab)use `\substack` from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\providecommand*{\coloneq}{\mathrel{\mathop:}=}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathcal{P}_{\left\{ \substack{\mathcal{B}\\[.5ex]\mathcal{F}} \right\}}
\Psi(\vec{r}_{1}, \vec{r}_{2}, \ldots, \vec{r}_{N})
\coloneq
\frac{1}{N !} \sum_{P} \xi^{P} \Psi(\vec{r}_{P 1} \vec{r}_{P 2} \ldots \vec{r}_{P N})
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you need this kind of construct often you can define an appropriate macro based on `\genfrac`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\foo}{\genfrac\{\}\z@{}}
\makeatother
\providecommand*{\coloneq}{\mathrel{\mathop:}=}

\begin{document}
\[
\foo{\mathcal{B}}{\mathcal{F}}, \quad
\mathcal{P}_{\foo{\mathcal{B}}{\mathcal{F}}}
\Psi(\vec{r}_{1}, \vec{r}_{2}, \ldots, \vec{r}_{N})
\coloneq
\frac{1}{N !} \sum_{P} \xi^{P} \Psi(\vec{r}_{P 1} \vec{r}_{P 2} \ldots \vec{r}_{P N})
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use a better name than `\foo`.

In both cases I removed the useless occurrences of `\left` and `\right`, and replaced `:=` by an appropriate macro with better alignment.

Please read also [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/82917)

Comment: Nice solution. For completeness Oberdiek wrote a package years back for ``:=` and friends, at ctan as `colonequals. `